# Websphere: log soap requests & responses

Tags: soap, websphere-7

I'm using **Websphere 7**. Using existing WSDL, I've created WS client using **wsimport** ant task (*com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport*).

Is there a way I can log SOAP xml requests/responses sent/received by this client?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Trace for SOAP WS messages can be enabled by following these steps on Websphere 7 administration console:

- Go to administration console
- Go to: Servers -> WebSphere application servers -> server > Change Log Detail Levels
- In the package tree find the package **com.ibm.ws.websvcs.trace**, click on package name and choose 'All Mesasges and Traces', as result you should have log details set as below:

> *=info: com.ibm.ws.websvcs.trace.*=all

- Click on 'OK' and then Save the changes.

SOAP request/responses can now be found in *trace.log* on your appl. server.

Answer (score 1):

For WebSphere Liberty Profile, logging of JAX-WS SOAP request and response messages can be enabled by adding the following trace configuration to the server.xml:

```
<logging traceFormat="BASIC" consoleLogLevel="INFO" traceSpecification="com.ibm.ws.jaxws.wsat.*=debug" traceFileName="stdout" />
```

Adding the `traceFileName="stdout"` attribute redirects the trace output to the console. Without this attribute it will write to the trace log file instead.